# Merged cell in custom table displaying in next column instead of next row

Tags: lightning-web-components, html, table

I have a list of records that needs to be grouped by store name and displayed on a table with a collapse/expand function. Table data is displayed properly when expanded, but is displayed as one row when collapsed. How do I prevent the grouped store names from displaying as one row? Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Collapsed Table
[image]
Expanded Table
[image]

sample.html

```
<template>
    <table class="slds-table slds-table_cell-buffer slds-table_bordered slds-table_col-bordered slds-table_striped slds-max-medium-table_stacked">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">
                        <div class="slds-truncate" title="">Store Name</div>
                    </th>
                    <th scope="col">
                        <div class="slds-truncate" title="">Contact Number</div>
                    </th>
                    <th scope="col">
                        <div class="slds-truncate" title="">Department</div>
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <template if:true={storeArray}>
                    <template for:each={storeArray} for:item="storeName">
                        <tr key={storeName.Store_Name__c} class="slds-hint-parent">
                            <td data-label="Store Name" rowspan={storeName.rowspan}>
                                {storeName.Store_Name__c} 
                                <lightning-button-icon icon-name="utility:chevrondown" alternative-text="Expand" class="slds-m-left_xx-small" onclick={handleExpand}></lightning-button-icon>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <template if:true={showChildren}>
                            <template for:each={storeName.stores} for:item="store">
                                <tr key={store.assetName}>
                                    <td key={store.Contact_Number__c} data-label="Contact Number">
                                        <lightning-formatted-phone value={store.Contact_Number__c}></lightning-formatted-phone>
                                    </td>
                                    <td key={store.Department__c} data-label="Department">
                                        {store.Department__c}
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </template>
                        </template>
                    </template>
                </template>
            </tbody>
        </table>
</template>
```

sample.js

```
import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';

export default class sample extends LightningElement {
    @track groupedDataMap = [];
    @track storeArray = [];
    @track showChildren = false;

    @track data = [
    {
        "Store_Name__c": "Store A",
        "Contact_Number__c": "12345678901",
        "Department__c": "Sales"
    },
    {
        "Store_Name__c": "Store A",
        "Contact_Number__c": "12345678902",
        "Department__c": "Marketing"
    },
    {
        "Store_Name__c": "Store B",
        "Contact_Number__c": "12345678903",
        "Department__c": "Sales"
    },
    {
        "Store_Name__c": "Store B",
        "Contact_Number__c": "12345678904",
        "Department__c": "Marketing"
    }
];
    connectedCallback() {
        this.groupedDataMap = new Map();

        this.data.forEach(store => {
            if (this.groupedDataMap.has(store.Store_Name__c)) {
                this.groupedDataMap.get(store.Store_Name__c).stores.push(store);
            } else {
                let newStore = {};
                newStore.Store_Name__c = store.Store_Name__c;
                newStore.stores = [store];
                this.groupedDataMap.set(store.Store_Name__c, newStore);
            }
        });
    
        let itr = this.groupedDataMap.values();
        let result = itr.next();
        while (!result.done) {
            result.value.rowspan = result.value.stores.length + 1;
            this.storeArray.push(result.value);
            result = itr.next();
        }
    }

    handleExpand() {
        this.showChildren = !this.showChildren;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome @XKCRanky.  Looking at your issue, but first a comment on your code.  Salesforce isn't entirely clear, unless you check really really closely, but they very much recommend that you do NOT use connectedCallback to set properties.  Use Setter and Getters... behavior is unpredictable if you use connectedCallback.  I don't think this is your issue, but it will remove a potential variable if you move the code to a getter/setter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I analyzed your code  by copying it in webcomponents.dev.

looks like it is happening due to rowspan. you are calculating rowspan in connectedcallback   and even if showchildren attribute is false   you are applying rowspan   which is showing incorrect display.

you should only apply rowspan  if   showchildren is true.

Webcompownnt.dev url : https://webcomponents.dev/edit/XmZ4s6hNbaCo56adbkGF/src/app.html

open preview in a new tab  for desktop view.

code to be modified

current code

```
<tbody>
                <template if:true={storeArray}>
                    <template for:each={storeArray} for:item="storeName">
                        <tr key={storeName.Store_Name__c} class="slds-hint-parent">
                            <td data-label="Store Name" rowspan={storeName.rowspan}>
                                {storeName.Store_Name__c} 
                                <lightning-button-icon icon-name="utility:chevrondown" alternative-text="Expand" class="slds-m-left_xx-small" onclick={handleExpand}></lightning-button-icon>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <template if:true={showChildren}>
                            <template for:each={storeName.stores} for:item="store">
                                <tr key={store.assetName}>
                                    <td key={store.Contact_Number__c} data-label="Contact Number">
                                        <lightning-formatted-phone value={store.Contact_Number__c}></lightning-formatted-phone>
                                    </td>
                                    <td key={store.Department__c} data-label="Department">
                                        {store.Department__c}
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </template>
                        </template>
                    </template>
                </template>
            </tbody>
```

modified code:

```
<tbody>
            <template if:true={storeArray}>
                <template for:each={storeArray} for:item="storeName">
                    <template if:false={showChildren}>
                        <tr key={storeName.Store_Name__c}>
                            <td data-label="Store Name">
                                {storeName.Store_Name__c}
                                <lightning-button-icon icon-name="utility:chevrondown" alternative-text="Expand"
                                    class="slds-m-left_xx-small" onclick={handleExpand}></lightning-button-icon>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </template>
                    <template if:true={showChildren}>
                        <tr key={storeName.Store_Name__c}>
                            <td data-label="Store Name" rowspan={storeName.rowspan}>
                                {storeName.Store_Name__c}
                                <lightning-button-icon icon-name="utility:chevrondown" alternative-text="Expand"
                                    class="slds-m-left_xx-small" onclick={handleExpand}></lightning-button-icon>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <template for:each={storeName.stores} for:item="store">
                            <tr key={store.assetName}>
                                <td key={store.Contact_Number__c} data-label="Contact Number">
                                    <lightning-formatted-phone value={store.Contact_Number__c}></lightning-formatted-phone>
                                </td>
                                <td key={store.Department__c} data-label="Department">
                                    {store.Department__c}
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </template>
                    </template>
                </template>
            </template>
        </tbody>
```

Comment: Thanks gaurav, that did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [`lightning-tree-grid`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-tree-grid/example) instead of writing your own component. That reduces your code to simply:

```
import { LightningElement } from "lwc";

export default class App extends LightningElement {
  treeData = []
  columns = [
    { fieldName: 'Store_Name__c', label: 'Store Name' },
    { fieldName: 'Contact_Number__c', label: 'Phone Number' },
    { fieldName: 'Department__c', label: 'Department' }
  ]
  data = [
    {
      "Store_Name__c": "Store A",
      "Contact_Number__c": "12345678901",
      "Department__c": "Sales"
    },
    {
      "Store_Name__c": "Store A",
      "Contact_Number__c": "12345678902",
      "Department__c": "Marketing"
    },
    {
      "Store_Name__c": "Store B",
      "Contact_Number__c": "12345678903",
      "Department__c": "Sales"
    },
    {
      "Store_Name__c": "Store B",
      "Contact_Number__c": "12345678904",
      "Department__c": "Marketing"
    }
  ];
  connectedCallback() {
    this.treeData = 
      // [2] Process all key-value pairs
      Object.entries(
        // [1] Map to store name
        this.data.reduce((p,v) => 
          (p[v.Store_Name__c] = [...(p[v.Store_Name__c] || []), v], p), {}
        )
        // [3] Convert to appropriate data format
      ).map(([Store_Name__c, _children]) => ({ Store_Name__c, _children }))
  }
}
```

---

```
<template>
    <lightning-tree-grid hide-checkbox-column data={treeData} columns={columns} key-field="Store_Name__c">
    </lightning-tree-grid>
</template>
```

---

Here's a [working example](https://webcomponents.dev/edit/UpKM4cgI7wE6mR73jBmw/src/app.html?p=stories).

---

Explanation of Code

---

The actual mapping function I used is a combination of a range of newer JavaScript syntax. I'll try to cover all of them.

`Object.entries` returns an Array of Array, where each index represents a key-value pair in the form of an Array `[key, value]`.

`([x, y]) => ({x, y})` is used to "destruct" the callback parameter, which is returned from `Object.entries`, to convert the key-value pair into an Array of `{ Store_Name__c, _children }` objects; `{x, y}` is shorthand for "take the values x and y and put them into an object with those attributes."

`Array.map` is used to convert a list from one type to another, here, we're converting the results from `Object.entries` to the desired `{ Store_Name__c, _children }` format expected by `lightning-tree-grid`.

`Array.reduce` is used to reduce an Array of elements into a single result; here, we're performing similar work as you did with the `Map`.

`(x, y) => (x = z, x)` uses an Arrow Function (`x => y`) for the callback. The `,` operator evaluates the left-hand value, then returns the right-hand value. In this code, we're taking the previous value, assigning a new value to it, then returning the previous value, such that we build an Object with keys for the `Store_Name__c` with a value of an Array for each.

`[...x, y]` returns an array, copied, with all the values of x, and the new value of y added to the end.

`(x || [])` returns `x` if it is not a falsy value (e.g. the Array has already been set for that store name), or a new empty Array `[]` otherwise. Because we're using this syntax, the above Array copy function needs parentheses, thus: `[...(x || []), y]`.

You'll want to do some reading on Arrow Functions, Rest parameters, destructuring assignments, Array.prototype.map, Array.prototype.reduce, Object.prototype.entries, the comma operator, and the shorthand object notation. All of those concepts are used here to create compact code.

Comment: Thanks sfdcfox. I tried debugging your reduce function. I am unable to understand it. How - [...(p[v.Store_Name__c] || [ ]), v], p),{}) is creating Store A: Array(1) .. . :|

Comment: @AnshulAgrawal That was a long writeup. Let me know if you need anything else explained.

Comment: Thank you sfdcfox for your detailed explanation.

Comment: Thank you sfdcfox for the detailed answer and explanation. I went the custom table route because lightning-tree-grid is not supported in mobile (view).